# Finding the optimal combination of a 5x5 array

Tags: math, optimization

Lets say I have a 5x5 array of numbers as shown

```
  p  q  r  s  t 
A 37 9  7  38 93
B 42 50 2  37 38
C 57 92 52 75 37
D 59 25 65 61 33
E 3  65 39 24 90
```

How can I write a program that will go through and find the smallest total value for all combinations of columns and rows. (No column or row can be used twice but they can be in any combination)

I don't really mind how messy the code gets, I'm just struggling to work out a brute force method of solving this problem.

Comment: Show us one example combination and the resulting value.

Comment: So for example... If A was paired with p, C with q, B with r, D with s and E with t then I would end up with 37+92+2+61+90=282. The aim of the program is to find the minimum possible total. (sorry for poor formatting, im on mobile at work)

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). It is solved efficiently by the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Comment: Awesome thanks, do you know of any existing c++ implementations of the hungarian algorithim?

Comment: This C implementation is referenced by the Wikipedia page for the Hungarian Algorithm: https://github.com/maandree/hungarian-algorithm-n3/blob/master/hungarian.c